# "Nice" in meaning of "beautiful" (externally) is correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I always thought that the word "**nice**" can be also a synonym for "**beautiful**" (external beauty or external appearance)
For example:

> **She is nice** = She looks  good.

but yesterday I was told by a non native English speaker that according to his native language dictionary (Ukrainian - [see here](http://linguisto.eu/dict/en)) the word "**nice**" doesn't refer to external beauty. Then I checked it out in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nice) in order to prove that "nice" refers also for external beauty, but to my great surprise I saw that there is no any consideration about external beauty among its definitions for the word "nice". So I'm already not sure if this meaning to this word is correct or not.

An example that simplify my meaning is:

> "There were two women there: one was fat and one was skinny. Who was
>   **nicer** (=looks better)?"

Comment: The other lesson here is never rely on a single dictionary to settle an argument. The word _nice_ has [many possible meanings](https://www.wordnik.com/words/nice); not every dictionary will list every one.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Anyway agree with me that it should not happen for a common meaning of word. It doesn't make sense that a common meaning would be omitted, unless it's a rare meaning then it more make sense, but it's not the case here. I believed (and maybe still believe) that it's not so rare meaning for "nice".

Comment: I won't agree with you here because (a) the dictionary you picked only listed three meanings (which should have been a clue to go start checking more dictionaries), and (b) one could argue that using _nice_ in this sense is at best an informalism (that is, it may be common in locker rooms filled with teenage boys, but you're unlikely to see _The Atlantic_ run an article with a sentence that reads, "She is nice" when they mean, "She is attractive").

Comment: And even when the context makes clear that we are talking about appearance, it's not a synonym of "beautiful". It's closer to "good-looking". It means she's in the top 50%, not that she's in the top 1%.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Nice can be used to describe anything pleasant or attractive**

---

[Nice](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nice) generally means:

> Giving pleasure or satisfaction; pleasant or attractive.

But can also specifically mean:

> (of a person) good-natured; kind.

---

That is, while you can absolutely describe a person as *nice* to mean attractive looking - some people may interpret you meaning that they are *kind* or *good-natured*, and not focusing on their external beauty.

---

To be unambiguous, it's most common to state the element you think is *nice*, otherwise most people's default (without surrounding conversation context) is to assume you mean *kind/good-natured*:

> She **looks** nice.
>   Who do you think **looks** nicer?

Otherwise some people may assume you are meaning:

> She is a **nice person**.

Which relates to her inner character.

---

Again, *nice* is such an overused/vague term in English - that it can be used to describe almost anything as having a positive/good quality. In general, you will never be *wrong* to describe something you like as *nice* - whether it's looks, character or anything else.

With such vague terms (e.g. "good"), it is best to state the exact thing you like - to avoid ambiguity. Although, to note, this is something native speakers can be bad at doing too.

Comment: Tone, body language, etc is important here. In speech you can be unambiguous without adding 'looks', although using "Nice" or "Very Nice" to describe someone's physical appearance can come across as crass to a native English Speaker.

Comment: It might help to know that "nice" is also frequently used ironically, to indicate displeasure with something bad.

Comment: For the most part, "nice" is pretty neutral---unless you explicitly state which aspect it is that one is nice in, be it looks or character. +1

Comment: Even "she looks nice" can be ambiguous. It could be interpreted to mean "she looks like a kind/good-natured person".

Comment: Nice answer! You should avoid **overusing** _nice_, but you shouldn't avoid **using** _nice_.

Comment: In "nice answer" I think you're using another sense of the word, meaning "precise or accurate".

Answer (score 10):

As a native speaker, I can assure you that "she is nice" would be interpreted, at least in AmE, as she is "kind", "polite", "sweet", etc and not "she is good looking".

There are some contexts where "nice" might mean pretty, but it would more along the lines of "Hey, check out this picture of the girl I met last night" "Nice!"

Answer (score 3):

“Nice” can refer to physical appearance in some contexts. But a sentence like “She/he is nice” would not be understood as referring to appearance. As mentioned in the comments, you would describe a person’s appearance with a sentence like “She/he looks nice.”

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on the context. You wouldn't use the adjective "nice" to refer to a good-looking person, but this would be - in my view - a perfectly valid choice (albeit vague and overused) to describe objects.
She's got such a nice house!
Your new car's very nice!

Comment: Yes you would use 'nice' for a person.  It is used that way all the time.